# How to pass text to an underlying iframe where an input reflecting iframe itself and have no input?

Tags: selenium, iframe

How to pass text to an underlying iframe where an input reflecting iframe itself and have no input?
Using Selenium or robot framework

Please find snapshot of html code

[image]
[image]

Comment: Do not post images, instead post HTML in text format, so we can replicate the same in our local machine.

Comment: Did you try switching to that particular frame first?

Comment: @Kazi yes already did the same but getting no such element